# How to format paragraphs in all table cells in LibreOffice Writer? Selecting doesn't work

Tags: text-formatting, libreoffice-writer

I am trying to set spacing above and below paragraph

[image]

in all cells of a table. Unfortunately, if affects only first cell of a selection. Is it possible to make bulk formatting?

Answer (score 0):

Just change the style that's used for table content. To do so, put the cursor into the table and hit <kbd>F11</kbd>. You'll see a list of styles, with "Table contents" highlighted (depending on your LO version, you may have to select it manually). Right-click on the style's name and select "Modify". All Modfications applied in the following window will affect all table cells (myabe except those that were manually formatted).